# Time complexity of mutually recursive functions

Tags: time-complexity, recursion

Suppose I have two mutually recursive functions like this:

```
f1(x)
{
   .//some code
   .
   .
   f1(x-1)+g1(x-1); 

}

g1(y)
{
   .
   .//some code
   g1(y-1)+f1(y-1);
  ..


}
```

How can I calculate time complexities in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set up recurrences, $T_1(n) = T_1(n-1) + T_2(n-1)$ and $T_2(n) = T_1(n-1) + T_2(n-1)$. So from there we can get that $T_1(n) = T_2(n)$, which implies that $T_1(n) = 2T_1(n-1)$. So for this, the two functions would be $O(2^n)$.