# Solving a system of recurrences

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

If the time complexity $T(n)$ of two functions $x(n)$ and $y(n)$ are mutually recursive, as in [Time complexity of mutually recursive functions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12742/time-complexity-of-mutually-recursive-functions), this gives $T(n)=O(2^n)$.  But how do you measure an algorithm with two or more (4 in the example below) recursive functions that are not necessarily mutually recursive?

**Example: Recursive Step Function**

$$
\begin{align*}
w(n)&=
\begin{cases}
w(n-1)+1 & \text{if } x(n-1)=y(n-1), \\
w(n-1) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} \\
x(n)&=8w(n). \\
y(n)&=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } w(n) > w(n-1), \\
y(n-1)+1 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} \\
z(n) &=
\begin{cases}
z(n-1)+1 & \text{if } z(n-1) < y(n-1) \text{ and } z(n-1)=1, \\
z(n-1)-1 & \text{if } z(n-1) < y(n-1) \text{ and } z(n-1)\neq 1, \\
z(n-1) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

These functions loop until $w(n)=I$ and then output the value of $z(n)$, where $I$ is the user input value.  This input value could be rather large.  I get the worse case scenario is dependent on $w(n)$, as it increases slowly.

I have calculated that the function specifically $$w(n)=O\left(\frac{\sqrt{16n+16}}{8}+\frac12\right),$$ but I am new to time complexity.  Could anyone help me to understand?

Here is the example in pseudocode:

```
SET w to 0
SET x to 1
SET y to 1
SET z to 0
GET i
REPEAT 
    IF z<y and z=1 THEN
        z=z+1 
    ELSEIF z<y and z != 1 THEN
        z=z-1
    ELSE do nothing
    IF x=y THEN
        w=w+1 and x=8*w and y=1
    ELSE 
        x=8*w and y=y+1
UNTIL w=i
PRINT z
```

Comment: Are w, x, y, z programs or running-time functions?

Comment: So you're trying to solve recurrences. That's a very different thing from what your title and tags suggest! Do not confuse algorithms and their running-time functions! Writing an algorithm that computes the running-time function is usually meaningless.

Comment: Jeff, @YuvalFilmus, please remove or flag the comments that can go!

Comment: @Jeff Then you've given me contradictory information. Maybe Yuval can edit the question to make sense, since he's apparently understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove by induction that it always holds that $z \leq 0$, and so $z \neq 1$ and $z < y$. This allows the following simplification:

- Input: $i$
- $x,y,z,w \gets 1,1,0,0$
- Repeat:
- - $z \gets z-1$
- - If $x = y$ then $w \gets w+1$ and $y \gets 1$; Else $y \gets y+1$
- - $x \gets 8w$
- Until $w = i$
- Return $z$

The running time is proportional to the number of iterations of the loop (which also happens to be the negation of the output).

In the first iteration we have $x=y$ and so set $w\gets 1$, $x\gets 8$, $y\gets 1$. Eight iterations later, we have $x=y=8$ (at the beginning of the iteration), and so we set $w\gets 2$, $x\gets 16$, $y\gets 1$. Sixteen iterations later, we have $x=y=16$, and so we set $w\gets 3$, $x\gets 24$, $y\gets 1$.

In total, we see that the number of iterations is
$$
1 + 8(1 + \cdots + (i-1)) = 1 + 8\frac{i(i-1)}{2} = 4i(i-1)+1 = (2i-1)^2.
$$
This shows that the output is $-(2i-1)^2$, and that the running time is $\Theta(i^2)$.